# Expandable List View Style

Tags: android, css

I am designing my expandablelistview's style. Are there any standards to making a listview/explistview look clean/nice/elegant. Could someone link me to some images or articles on this. I havn't been able to find any. So far the cleanest explistview I have found is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxpIj.jpg or https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/38/db/67/38db678ea2528447f24cbd0fdaaf40ad.jpg

I can model or replicate something like this quite easily, but was wondering if there are more modern ways/styles out there